# unfortunately app name has stopped

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm new to eclipse and wanted to know how to keep this message

unfortunately app name  has stopped

from showing every time I run my Test Application in my AVD. I'm trying to make a LineView Layout and Eclipse shows no mistakes. So how can I fix this and how can I find out what the problem is if Eclipse shows no problems?

(Here's a copy of my Logcat)

```
12-23 06:51:56.591: D/AndEngine(2754): MenuActivity.onCreate @(Thread: 'main')
12-23 06:51:56.641: D/dalvikvm(2754): Trying to load lib /data/app-     lib/com.electricpunch.beetlesmasher-1/libandengine.so 0xb3cffc08
12-23 06:51:56.651: D/dalvikvm(2754): Added shared lib /data/app-  lib/com.electricpunch.beetlesmasher-1/libandengine.so 0xb3cffc08
12-23 06:51:56.651: D/dalvikvm(2754): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.electricpunch.beetlesmasher-1/libandengine.so 0xb3cffc08, skipping init
12-23 06:51:56.831: D/AndEngine(2754): MenuActivity.onResume @(Thread: 'main')
12-23 06:51:57.151: W/dalvikvm(2754): threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a39ba8)
12-23 06:51:57.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2754): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 90
12-23 06:51:57.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2754): Process: com.electricpunch.beetlesmasher, PID: 2754
12-23 06:51:57.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2754): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No EGLConfig found!
12-23 06:51:57.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2754):     at org.andengine.opengl.view.ConfigChooser.chooseConfig(ConfigChooser.java:229)
12-23 06:51:57.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2754):     at org.andengine.opengl.view.ConfigChooser.chooseConfig(ConfigChooser.java:203)
12-23 06:51:57.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2754):     at   android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1024)
12-23 06:51:57.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2754):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1401)
12-23 06:51:57.161: E/AndroidRuntime(2754):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
12-23 06:51:57.311: I/Choreographer(2754): Skipped 93 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-23 06:51:57.481: D/gralloc_goldfish(2754): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-23 06:51:58.161: D/AndEngine(2754): MenuActivity.onPause @(Thread: 'main')
12-23 06:52:01.171: D/AndEngine(2754): MenuActivity.onDestroy @(Thread: 'main')
12-23 06:52:02.871: D/AndEngine(2754): UpdateThread interrupted. Don't worry - this EngineDestroyedException is most likely expected!
12-23 06:52:02.871: D/AndEngine(2754): org.andengine.engine.Engine$EngineDestroyedException
12-23 06:52:02.871: D/AndEngine(2754):  at org.andengine.engine.Engine.throwOnDestroyed(Engine.java:594)
12-23 06:52:02.871: D/AndEngine(2754):  at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTickUpdate(Engine.java:580)
12-23 06:52:02.871: D/AndEngine(2754):  at org.andengine.engine.Engine$UpdateThread.run(Engine.java:858)
12-23 06:52:04.591: D/AndEngine(2754): MenuActivity.onDestroyResources @(Thread: 'main')
12-23 06:52:04.591: D/AndEngine(2754): MenuActivity.onGameDestroyed @(Thread: 'main')
12-23 06:52:04.961: I/Process(2754): Sending signal. PID: 2754 SIG: 9
```

(Here's a copy of my AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.electricpunch.beetlesmasher"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="4323000"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.electricpunch.beetlesmasher.MenuActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.electricpunch.beetlesmasher.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.electricpunch.beetlesmasher.GameActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

(Here's a copy of my MenuActivity.java)

```
package com.electricpunch.beetlesmasher;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.andengine.audio.music.Music;
import org.andengine.audio.music.MusicFactory;
import org.andengine.audio.sound.Sound;
import org.andengine.audio.sound.SoundFactory;
import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
import org.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.FillResolutionPolicy;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.background.SpriteBackground;
import org.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.andengine.entity.text.Text;
import org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent;
import org.andengine.opengl.font.Font;
import org.andengine.opengl.font.FontFactory;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.ITexture;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureOptions;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.ITextureRegion;
import org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import com.electricpunch.beetlesmasher.R;
import com.electricpunch.beetlesmasher.other.Prefs;
import com.electricpunch.beetlesmasher.other.Tags;
import com.electricpunch.beetlesmasher.other.TextButton;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.googlesamples.gameutils.GameHelper;
import com.googlesamples.gameutils.GameHelper.GameHelperListener;
public class MenuActivity extends SplashScreenActivity {

Camera mCamera;

BitmapTextureAtlas mBGAtlas, mWindowAtlas, mButtonAtlas, mSoundButtonAtlas,
        mCrossAtlas, mLeaderboardAtlas;

ITextureRegion mBGTextureRegion, mWindowTextureRegion,
        mButtonTextureRegion, mSoundButtonTextureRegion,
        mCrossTextureRegion, mLeaderboardTextureRegion;

Font headFont, menuFont;

Sound clickSound;
Music music;

Sprite cross;

SharedPreferences mSettings;

Boolean useGooglePlayServices = false;
GameHelper mGameHelper; //needed for leaderbord

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (!useGooglePlayServices)
        return;
    // create game helper with all APIs (Games, Plus, AppState):
    mGameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_ALL);
    // enable debug logs (if applicable)
    GameHelperListener listener = new GameHelper.GameHelperListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSignInSucceeded() {
            ShowLeaderboard();
        }
        @Override
        public void onSignInFailed() {
            // handle sign-in failure (e.g. show Sign In button)
        }
    };
    mGameHelper.setup(listener);
}

void ShowLeaderboard() {
    if (getHighScore() > 0)
        setHighScore(getHighScore());
    startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent
                          (mGameHelper.getApiClient(), getString
                          (R.string.leaderboard)), 0);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (useGooglePlayServices)
        mGameHelper.onStart(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (useGooglePlayServices)
        mGameHelper.onStop();
}

void setHighScore(int score) {
    if (mGameHelper.isSignedIn()) //if user is signed in - new highscore will be addeds 
        Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGameHelper.getApiClient(), getString(R.string.leaderboard), score);
}

public int getHighScore() {
    return mSettings.getInt("score", 0);    
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
    mGameHelper.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
}

@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, Prefs.cameraWidth, Prefs.cameraHeight);
    EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true,
            ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_FIXED, new FillResolutionPolicy(),
            mCamera);
    engineOptions.getRenderOptions().setDithering(true);
    engineOptions.getAudioOptions().setNeedsSound(true);
    engineOptions.getAudioOptions().setNeedsMusic(true);
    return engineOptions;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!isFinishing())
        finish();
}

@Override
public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene,
        OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback)
        throws IOException {
    pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();
}

@Override
public synchronized void onGameCreated() {
    super.onGameCreated();
}

@Override
protected synchronized void onResume() {
    getEngine().getSoundManager().setMasterVolume(1);
    getEngine().getMusicManager().setMasterVolume(1);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    getEngine().getSoundManager().setMasterVolume(0);
    getEngine().getMusicManager().setMasterVolume(0);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected Scene onAssetsLoaded() {
    Scene scene = new Scene();
    // add wood background image
    scene.setBackground(new SpriteBackground(new Sprite(
            Prefs.cameraWidth / 2, Prefs.cameraHeight / 2,
            mBGTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager())));
    // game name
    Text nameText1 = new Text(Prefs.cameraWidth / 2,
            Prefs.cameraHeight - 150, headFont, "Beetle",
            getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    Text nameText2 = new Text(Prefs.cameraWidth / 2,
            Prefs.cameraHeight - 250, headFont, "Smasher",
            getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    scene.attachChild(nameText1);
    scene.attachChild(nameText2);
    // add menu window
    Sprite window = new Sprite(Prefs.cameraWidth / 2,
            Prefs.cameraHeight / 2, mWindowTextureRegion,
            getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    window.setZIndex(5);
    window.setAlpha(0.7f);
    scene.attachChild(window);
    // add resume button
    TextButton playButton = new TextButton(scene, Prefs.cameraWidth / 2,
            Prefs.cameraHeight / 2 + 100, mButtonTextureRegion, menuFont,
            "Play", getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        GameActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                if (Prefs.soundEnabled)
                    clickSound.play();
            }
            super.onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX,
                    pTouchAreaLocalY);
            return true;
        }
    };
    playButton.setZIndex(6);
    scene.registerTouchArea(playButton);
    scene.attachChild(playButton);
    TextButton exitButton = new TextButton(scene, Prefs.cameraWidth / 2,
            Prefs.cameraHeight / 2 - 100, mButtonTextureRegion, menuFont,
            "Exit", getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {
                finish();
            } else if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                if (Prefs.soundEnabled)
                    clickSound.play();
            }
            super.onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX,
                    pTouchAreaLocalY);
            return true;
        }
    };
    exitButton.setZIndex(6);
    scene.registerTouchArea(exitButton);
    scene.attachChild(exitButton);
    // add sound button with cross
    cross = new Sprite(0, 0, mCrossTextureRegion,
            getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    cross.setVisible(false);
    cross.setZIndex(6);
    Sprite soundButton = new Sprite(Prefs.cameraWidth / 2 + 250, 200,
            mSoundButtonTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                if (Prefs.soundEnabled) {
                    Prefs.soundEnabled = false;
                    Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("sound", false);
                    editor.apply();
                    music.pause();
                    cross.setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    Prefs.soundEnabled = true;
                    Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("sound", true);
                    editor.apply();
                    music.resume();
                    cross.setVisible(false);
                }
                if (Prefs.soundEnabled)
                    clickSound.play();
                setScale(0.7f);
            } else if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {
                setScale(0.8f);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    soundButton.setScale(0.8f);
    soundButton.setZIndex(5);
    scene.attachChild(soundButton);
    scene.registerTouchArea(soundButton);
    cross.setPosition(soundButton);
    cross.setScale(0.5f);
    cross.setAlpha(0.7f);
    scene.attachChild(cross);
    if (useGooglePlayServices) {
        Sprite recordsButton = new Sprite(Prefs.cameraWidth / 2 - 250, 200,
                mLeaderboardTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                    float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                    if (!mGameHelper.isSignedIn()) 
                        mGameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
                    else
                        ShowLeaderboard();
                    if (Prefs.soundEnabled)
                        clickSound.play();
                    setScale(0.7f);
                } else if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {
                    setScale(0.8f);
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
        recordsButton.setScale(0.8f);
        recordsButton.setZIndex(5);
        scene.attachChild(recordsButton);
        scene.registerTouchArea(recordsButton);
    }
    // read prefs
    mSettings = getSharedPreferences("Settings", 0);
    Prefs.soundEnabled = mSettings.getBoolean("sound", true);
    if (Prefs.soundEnabled) {
        music.play();
    } else {
        cross.setVisible(true);
    }
    int highscore = mSettings.getInt("score", 0);
    if (highscore > 0) {
        Text highscore_text = new Text(Prefs.cameraWidth / 2, 210,
                menuFont, "Highscore", getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        highscore_text.setScale(0.5f);
        scene.attachChild(highscore_text);
        Text highscore_num = new Text(Prefs.cameraWidth / 2, 155, menuFont,
                Integer.toString(highscore), 100,
                getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        highscore_num.setScale(0.5f);
        scene.attachChild(highscore_num);
    }
    scene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
    scene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionMoveEnabled(true);
    scene.sortChildren();
    return scene;
}

@Override
protected void assetsToLoad() {
    // creating game atlases
    mBGAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(getTextureManager(), 1024, 2048,
            TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
    mWindowAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(getTextureManager(), 1024, 512,
            TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
    mWindowAtlas.addEmptyTextureAtlasSource(0, 0, 1024, 512);
    mButtonAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(getTextureManager(), 512, 256,
            TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
    mButtonAtlas.addEmptyTextureAtlasSource(0, 0, 512, 256);
    mSoundButtonAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(getTextureManager(), 256,
            256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
    mSoundButtonAtlas.addEmptyTextureAtlasSource(0, 0, 256, 256);
    mCrossAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(getTextureManager(), 256, 256,
            TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
    mCrossAtlas.addEmptyTextureAtlasSource(0, 0, 256, 256);
    mLeaderboardAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(getTextureManager(), 256,
            256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
    mLeaderboardAtlas.addEmptyTextureAtlasSource(0, 0, 256, 256);
    // creating texture regions
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .setAssetBasePath("gfx/interface/");
    mBGTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(mBGAtlas, getAssets(), "bg.png", 0, 0);
    mWindowTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(mWindowAtlas, getAssets(), "window.png", 0, 0);
    mButtonTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(mButtonAtlas, getAssets(), "button.png", 0, 0);
    mSoundButtonTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(mSoundButtonAtlas, getAssets(),
                    "sound_button.png", 0, 0);
    mCrossTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(mCrossAtlas, getAssets(), "cross.png", 0, 0);
    mLeaderboardTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
            .createFromAsset(mLeaderboardAtlas, getAssets(),
                    "leaderboard.png", 0, 0);
    // loading atlases
    mBGAtlas.load();
    mWindowAtlas.load();
    mButtonAtlas.load();
    mSoundButtonAtlas.load();
    mCrossAtlas.load();
    mLeaderboardAtlas.load();
    // loading fonts
    FontFactory.setAssetBasePath("fonts/");
    BitmapTextureAtlas fontAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(
            getTextureManager(), 512, 512,
            TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
    fontAtlas.addEmptyTextureAtlasSource(0, 0, 512, 512);
    final ITexture fontTexture = fontAtlas;
    menuFont = FontFactory.createFromAsset(getFontManager(), fontTexture,
            getAssets(), "font.ttf", 80, true, Color.BLACK);
    menuFont.load();
    BitmapTextureAtlas fontAtlas2 = new BitmapTextureAtlas(
            getTextureManager(), 512, 512,
            TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
    fontAtlas2.addEmptyTextureAtlasSource(0, 0, 512, 512);
    final ITexture fontTexture2 = fontAtlas2;
    headFont = FontFactory
            .createFromAsset(getFontManager(), fontTexture2, getAssets(),
                    "headfont.ttf", 100, true, Color.rgb(100, 167, 60));
    headFont.load();
    // loading sounds
    SoundFactory.setAssetBasePath("sfx/");
    try {
        clickSound = SoundFactory.createSoundFromAsset(getEngine()
                .getSoundManager(), this, "click.mp3");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // loading music
    MusicFactory.setAssetBasePath("mfx/");
    try {
        music = MusicFactory.createMusicFromAsset(getEngine()
                .getMusicManager(), this, "menu.mp3");
        music.setVolume(music.getVolume() / 1.7f);
        music.setLooping(true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No EGLConfig found!

Answer (score 0):

I think your emulator doesn`t have GPU. Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
The problem seems to be in emulator. try Genymotion, not AVD, and use modern versions of android. 
above 4.2 
https://www.genymotion.com/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter#!/download
Its much faster and awesome

Comment: i test my app in my smartphone s2 and s3 is not work